# Dependency error in Spring Boot and Elastic Search maven application

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, elasticsearch

I am creating application using Spring Boot, Spring Data, and Elasticsearch.
I am following [this guide](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-spring-data-elasticsearch-example/). I'm using Maven as my build tool. I am using IntelliJ IDEA as my primary IDE, and I created the Maven project using my IDE.

Here is my `pom.xml` file, that I created according to the tutorial.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>1</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot-springdata-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Package as an executable jar/war -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I am facing this error message:

> Project '''org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:1.5.1.RELEASE''' not found.
>   Inspects a Maven model for resolution problems.

As well as this one:

> Dependency '''org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch:''' not found. 
>   Inspects a Maven model for resolution problems.

And this one too:

> Dependency '''org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:''' not found.
>   Inspects a Maven model for resolution problems.

And the same error messages for other dependencies.

Comment: I would consider checking your Maven settings. Which repositories are configured?

Comment: Looks like the dependencies have not been downloaded. Did Intellij prompt you to download these packages?

Comment: @alltej Yeah i did. And also I downloaded..... Is there anything else i need to change in the code ?